# Can't add modules to installed Unity editors

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, editor

I'm trying to add the Android SDK Module to an Editor that I have installed on my PC.

I've looked it up online and the guide available [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedAddingEditorComponents.html) states that there should be an "Add Modules" option available from the menu but it is absent from the menu when I open it in my Unity Hub:

[image: "Add Modules" option missing from the menu in Unity Hub]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

None of above answers worked for me. The answer is here:

1. first locate your editor from *unityhub*
2. quit from *unityhub* completely
3. go to this path:

> *C:\Users\**username**\AppData\Roaming\UnityHub*\

4. find this file: `editors.json`
5. locate the line of your desired version :

> {"2019.4.15f1":{"version":"2019.4.15f1", . . .

6. At the end of this line change `"manual":true` to `"manual":false`
7. reopen *unityhub* again and enjoy!

Comment: This makes the option appear but you cannot actually add modules.

Comment: Did not work - "No modules were found for Unity 2019.4.x"

Comment: @Logic1 I've heard it before. not sure about the cause of your issue unfortunately!

Answer (score 11):

I've solved the issue by reinstalling the Unity Editor version I was using via the Unity Hub.

It seems that Unity Hub doesn't have the option to add modules to Unity Editor versions which have been installed using the Unity Installer instead of Unity Hub itself.

It is worth pointing out that [Brian Choi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56817781/28411) is a valid workaround, however I wanted to use the modules functionality of Unity Hub.

Answer (score 7):

I got strait solution for this issue

No reinstall require.
No redownload require.
One click Restore all unity editors including Modules.

1. Remove Unity editor from the hub.
2. Go to Unity hub setting.
3. From General tab you will find the default editors path.
4. Locate the path and hit save.
5. Enjoy. :)

[image]

Comment: Hm, my Unity version is readded but still doesn't have the "Add Modules" button :/

Comment: Try to move the editor to the default location if it's not there then repeat the steps

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I ended up using Don Andre's solution below.

Answer (score 5):

1. Press three dots
2. Remove from hub
3. Go to https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
4. Press unity installer
5. After this it will show message "You already have this unity version installed"
6. Now this Add modules option will appear.

Comment: Hm, I get that message, but the "Add modules option" still does not appear :/

Answer (score 5):

Visiting the release notes for an old version provides direct download links to the individual build modules, example: https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.4.4

1. Go the download archive: https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive
2. Find your version
3. Click "Release Notes"
4. All downloads sorted by editor platform (Windows editor + Mac editor) should be linked

[image: screenshot of downloads for example release]

Comment: I still cant find links to download android ndk for that version

Comment: I think this is the right way to add module

Answer (score 4):

You can give any tools with this:

1. Install Unity Hub.
2. Run Unity Hub.
3. Go to this page:
   [image: screen shot]
4. Then click on the Unity Hub.
5. In the next level you can select your tools and give them.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked, and judging by the comments on the other answers, this should really be the accepted answer imo

Answer (score 2):

1. Run UnityEditor
2. Open menu 'Unity/Preferences/External Tools'
3. There is menu for Android SDK, and buttons to download SDK.

Comment: As of 2020, Unity has now deliberately removed these buttons, in an attempt to force more people to use the (still buggy!) UnityHub :(

Comment: @Adam that's the savagest thing i've ever heard from unity . I can't believe they actually do that. They took away our manual install and gives us a buggy automatic install which forces us to reinstall our unity from unity hub if we previously install it using the unity download assistant, i'm amazed .

Comment: Not to mention that as of 2024 there are still issues with hub adding shaders in their latest LTS release (2022).  The only way I could get it to properly install in windows was by doing it manually.  Now what...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this hope that work for you.

1. Open Unity
2. Go to File menu --> Build Settings
3. from Platform select any module .
4. Click Open Download Page .

It will download  .exe file for this module targetting the same unity version you have .
just install it .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot realy add modules from the Hub,try the web version instead.

1. Press This Link: https://unity.com/releases/editor/qa/lts-releases
2. Find your LTS version here
3. Click to expand the menu and see the modules listed.
4. Click on the modules to download an installer
5. Open the installer,finish the steps required and done!

Answer (score 1):

1. Best way to manage Unity modules is using Unity Hub. As Don Andre post reinstalling Unity.
2. For those Unity version can't installed from Unity Hub, you can only use Unity installer.

Some Tips for second way:

- Install all required modules at once. Because you can only re-install Unity but not modify, it's a waste of time.
- After locate installed Unity in Unity Hub, you can't modify modules, so you can't modify modules or install Android SDK or NDK. I recommend download SDK & NDK outside, and open menu 'Edit/Preferences/External Tools', set SDK & NDK path.
- You can found Android NDK requirement from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

[image]

- NDK download link: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html#ndk-16b-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Here are our real options.

1. Completely remove everything with unity and then install the last version of 2018 before they make using that without the crap hub impossible and just never update it.
2. Get rid of it completely and, use a competitor's product and deal with the learning curve,
3. Congratulate Unity for destroying their own product and going backwards and never use their stuff ever again.

I have been a long time user and I and others were going to create a community of gamers and indie developers for a joint volunteer project. With this crap a lot of us are now considering Unreal because Unity has tanked us, ignored us, and claim fixes that are not fixed for the last damn time.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers don't work for you or anyone else reading this, then try these steps (worked for me):

1. Verify that you don't have the modules.json file in the desired version folder (Eg: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.3.15f1\modules.json).
2. Copy the modules.json file from one of your working versions and replace the version numbers within the file with the new version number (Eg: Replace any 2019.3.6 (copied version) with 2019.3.15 (desired version)).
3. Restart Unity Hub. For good measure I killed all Unity Hub processes too.

You should now be able to install a new module.

**Please note** that I did not do any testing around if the currently installed modules from the copied version, in my example above it would be 2019.3.6, would carry over correctly to the desired version or if it caused any issues. For me it so happened that I had the same modules already installed for both versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I had other installs of Unity. The version that didn't have the "Add Modules" option also happened to missing the "modules.json" file under applications/Unity/Hub/Editors/2021.3.16f1. So I simply copy and pasted the one I had under the 2021.3.13f1 folder. I completely restarted the Unity Hub (hit the red x and also right clicked and selected "quit" (on Mac)) then restarted Unity Hub and the "Add Modules" option was now present. I was then able to add the module I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the unity folder is within the unity hub folder.
You can then remove the version in the Unity Hub.
Then go to https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive and find the version you want to install. You should be able to select the added modules now.

[image: The unity version folder must be inside the hub]

Answer (score 1):

Re-Installing it via Unity Hub helped me. To find your version go to [this](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive) link.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's slightly different from Nek0pi

1. Remove Unity from Hub
2. go to unity archive (https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive)
3. in the website, click Unity Hub button next to Unity version that you're looking for (in my case its Unity 2019.3.13)
4. Unity Hub will pop up and let you add any modules you want in that selected version.

After all those steps, next time you clicked on the three dots, it'll show Add Modules option.

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiB92.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your Unity editor is in the right folder location, (check below), and you should normally see a link to add modules on clicking the three dots for your install on Unity Hub afterwards.

The typical location on each OS will be;

Windows

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe
```

OR

```
C:\Program Files\Unity<version>\Editor\Unity.exe
```

macOS

```
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/<version>/Unity.app
```

Linux

```
/home/<username>/Unity/Hub/Editor/<version>/Unity
```

[Read more](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedInstallingHub.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in Unity 2020.2.1f1.

The *problem is just of path*.

The .exe file of module that you downloaded has a path in it which it isn't able to find.

The default path that it will accept is :

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.1f1\Editor

In the case if you have downloaded the unity editor without installer then your unity editor will be saved as:

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.1f1
```

So you need to move files from

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.1f1 to
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.1f1\Editor
```

and then execute your downloaded .exe module and give it path `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.1f1\Editor`

This will install your module at right place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here, I solved choosing the same path of unity editors folder before mod installation

Answer (score -3):

For just a beta version you can simply add the module :-

1. Open unity hub
2. Go to installs
3. Click on the three dots on your beta version
4. Click on add modules
5. Check the required module
6. Agree for the terms and condition
7. Install

There you go