# How to install recommended SDK and JDK in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do I install recommended sdk and Ndk Jdk `1.8.0_152 1`?

As per this warning:
[image: Screenshot from Unity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting up your  project from the (unity) Hub you can check to download which packs you will need (such as Android). The dependencies you need should be included with that (Unity 2019.2.0b4 should work if you're running into issues still).

If there is an issue with the NDK then this version should work with that release:
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64.zip

It might say you're not using the recommended NDK, but it should still build.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this link
[Install Android Build Support and the Android SDK & NDK tools](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can add modules directly from Unity Hub:
[image: Screenshot of Unity hub]

If "Add modules" does not show up see
[Can't add modules to installed Unity editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817573/cant-add-modules-to-installed-unity-editors), although you will probably need to just uninstall-reinstall the editor [through Hub](https://unity.com/releases/editor/archive):

[image: Installing via Hub]

If you get a "ghost" install in Hub (an entry for a version of Unity you no-longer have installed) you'll have to do some fiddling to fix it:

1. Open `%appdata%\Roaming\UnityHub\editors.json`
2. Remove the section (`, {...}`) that pertains to your ghost version
3. Save the file and restart your machine (restarting Hub seems to be insufficient somehow)