# how to switch platforms in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

hiii i am new to unity, and i want to switch my platform to android. but, the problem is, when i click the android in build settings, it says "no android module loaded". and when i click to install with unity hub, it says "the unity version 2019.4.13f1 is already located by the hub. You cannot add modules to a located hub". how to resolve this issue ?? and i have also tried installing unity installer and when the downloading completes, it says "failed to locate unity.exe".... can someone pls help me with this.. I am trying this since past few days, and it has become annoying :(.. plssss somebody helpp.....

Comment: You can still add modules to already installed Unity versions .. but only if this version was installed via the Hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this post:
[Can't add modules to installed Unity editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817573/cant-add-modules-to-installed-unity-editors)

It says no reinstall required. But I would try that next.

It cannot hurt to read this as well:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html